# How can I track what has changed in a viewmodel in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used mvvm frameworks like Knockout and Kendo UI, but these frameworks are based on event listeners, and AngularJS uses dirty tracking. How can I attach to an event or use a function to get the modified properties on an AngularJS model so I can use that information for an Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$watch` function, [See documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)

```
    $scope.$watch('yourVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       alert(' yourVar has changed!');
   });
```